# Marketing Cloud Query Activity SQL Syntax Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

New to SQL so be nice! :)

I'm trying to run a simple SQL query in Automation studio, unfortunately I am getting this error - "***An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.***"

```
select Account_ID, First_Name, Gender, Communication Key, Email_Address,
SubscriberKey from [TEST_De]
where Subscriberkey not in (select Subscriberkey from _sent where JobID = XXXXXX)
```

Now, straight away the empty character in `Communication Key` stands out as the culprit. However please note that this is exactly how the field is presented in the DE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns that contain space or use reserved SQL keyword needs to be wrapped in the square brackets so that the query knows it is a single Column.

Use `[Communication Key]`, and all should work.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know Mateusz :)